# Should 400 and 500 error pages be static .html files?

Tags: http, web-applications

When building web applications should error pages (400, 500 status codes) be static .html files or is it fine to serve up dynamic pages and why?

I would think that if your server goes down, your dynamic pages would go down with it. At least with static pages, your load balancer could serve up static files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as the HTTP protocol is concerned, there is no difference between a static and a dynamic page, so *standards* wise, there is no problem in serving up a dynamic page for a 400 and 500.

However, as you say, if there is an error in your application, then trying to serve up a dynamic page is probably not the best idea as it will possibly fail due to the same error, or even exacerbate the problem if the error is due to database congestion etc.

Comment: I think I almost answered my own question but just wanted some affirmation.

Comment: Probably true, but never hurts to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It might be interesting to look through your server logs and see which errors occur most. Usually I find that there's always loads of 404s for content not found. Not because of broken links within sites/applications but just random requests for pages that don't exist by spiders/spammers.

A dynamic 404 page may add extra load to your server but it depends on the volume of those errors as to how much time your server will spend having to dynamically generate those error pages.

If you have a dynamically-generated 404 error page then I would recommend creating a blank robots.txt file and a blank/plain favicon.ico file. Or dropping requests for at least favicons in your .htaccess. Doing that can help reduce the number of 404s so having a dynamic 404 error page may cause less of an impact.

Essentially though there's nothing wrong with it - it just might not be the best idea from a pure performance point of view. It depends on how loaded your server/application is in the first place really and how much headroom your server has.

Answer (score 0):

I think a differentiation between 404s and server error (500s) is useful.

One important function I'd like to offer users that end up with a 404 is the ability to search for other content, which is a function served by the main app. Sure you can redo the search on static pages but that's redundant.

The main cause for a 404 is either content has moved or it no longer exists, and in this case, providing search is of value. Not all users facing 404 are results of a server being down or an application error.

tl;dr I'd have my 500s reside on a static server, and provide dual layers for 404, the first to be served from within the (dynamic) app, and as a failsafe layer, another 404 route to a page on my static server.